# Redireccionar a una página web con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito redireccionar desde Javascript a una página web, conozco esta manera para hacerlo desde HTML

```
<form action="https://trello.com/app-key/">
  <input type="submit" class="nobutton"value="Consiga su API_KEY aquí"/> 
</form>
```

Pero necesito hacer algo parecido desde una funcion de Javascript, así tengo definido el button

```
<input type="button" id="btn" class="button" value="Login"/>
```

y necesito que en esta función además de otras cosas que ya tengo implementadas me redirija a una pagina web

```
  ('#btn').click(function() {

  $(window).load(function(){

   Trello.authorize({
   name: "Task Slayer",
   type: "popup",
   interactive: true,
   expiration: "never",
   persist: false,
   success: function () { onTrelloAuthorizeSuccessful(); },
   scope: { write: true, read: true },
   });

// Save the token after success call
     function onTrelloAuthorizeSuccessful() {
        var token = Trello.token();
        document.write(token);
        return token;        
    }


    });
    }
```

Comment: ¿Has probado en buscar en Google? Lo digo más que nada porque salen miles de resultados (en español) con la solución, no es que no pretenda ayudarte pero preguntas que están respondiendas en la propia documentacion de un lenguaje de programación pues quiere decir que has buscado poco

Comment: Sí, he buscado en google, y mi problema lo tengo porque no entiendo cómo conseguir invocar a la función Trello.authorice, ya que ese código con un <script> EN html si funciona pero no consigo pasarlo bien, gracias.

Comment: pues entonces tú pregunta está mal formulada

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias formas, con Javascript puro, prueba cualquiera de estos 2:
`window.location.replace("https://www.ejemplo.com");` //redirecciona y si haces back no regresas a la pagina original

`window.location.href = "https://www.ejemplo.com";`    //con back regresas a la página original

con jQuery:

```
var url = "https://www.ejemplo.com";    
$(location).attr('href',url);
```